# Name grid-template-rows in SASS

Tags: css, sass, css-grid

Just writing `grid-template-columns: [first] 15% [second] 100fr  [third] 15%` works if we do it in pure CSS but when I do it in SASS I get an error. 
But if I check the [SASS docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html) and search for "grid" the first hit is a line that explains that I should be able to use brackets… But there are no examples showing the exact syntax that should be used and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Try that way:

`grid-template-columns: unquote("[first] 15% [second] 100fr [third] 15%");`